# Can't open a terminal in Ubuntu 22.04, running in VirtualBox 7.0 on a Windows 11 host machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-11, linux-terminal

I just installed VirtualBox 7.0 and made a new virtual Ubuntu 22.04.1 machine on my Windows 11 PC. I can run programs like libreoffice, etc, but I cannot open a terminal.

I've tried to activate the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" feature, but still no luck.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 running as a VM on Windows 11 Pro using VMware. Terminal works fine. Spin up a new Ubuntu and see if Terminal works in that

Comment: It doesn't open even for Ctrl-Alt-T shortcut?

Comment: No. A "terminal icon" appears, indicating that Ubuntu is trying to open it, but it never appears on the desktop. ALso, I've tried the "open folder in terminal" by right-clicking a folder, but still no luck

Comment: I'll try to run the "update software" from the "Ubuntu software" application...

Comment: I've edited the post - including a solution. Credits to Hamed Kamrava

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I got the same issue, and I solved it on bizarre way: 
In your Ubuntu open settings and go to ***Language and Region*** and switch language to some other (for example Canadian English) and restart VM and terminal will work. 
If you try to back it to previous language, you also could do it, it worked also for me.

Comment: Yeah this works fine for me
VB 7.0 and ubuntu ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 version

I change the language to Canada English

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Virtual Box 7.0 and Ubuntu 20.04.5LTS.

I also changed the line of /etc/default/locale file to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`  and rebooted. If you dont have privilleges to change it, you can Alt+F2 and write `gedit admin:/etc/default/locale`

Answer (score 2):

I also changed the line of `/etc/default/locale` file to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8` and rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by checking the 'Skip unattended installation' option while creating the Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox. Using VirtualBox 7.0, the checkbox can be found on the first screen when creating a new VM. I have marked the checkbox in red in the image below. Judging from other Q&A regarding this issue, I'm guessing this works because it asks you your locale during the installation, while it doesn't if you choose for an unattended installation.

This doesn't really change anything about the installation process except that you have to enter credentials and other info while installing Ubuntu, instead of through the VirtualBox wizard before installing.

[image: First step of adding a new VM to VirtualBox]